# What is the next number of this sequence? Does the form play any role?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Got this series from a friend in this patricular form:

```
  1 2 1 1
  1 2 3 1
2 1 1 2 1 3
2 2 3 1 1 3
?????????????
```

I don't really know if the form has anything to do with the series and don't know if it is a mathematical series... any clues on what is next and most importantly why?

Comment: It would help if you were to give context for where this quetsion comes from.

Comment: no context around it... it's just that on an empty notebook page... there is a change the follow up is: 
     222321
     421311
    11123113 , but not sure if this is right. He told me that these 4 lines where enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar to the look-and-say but you count the TOTAL number occurrences of the first integer in the above line then proceed to the next integer that appears.

1

11

21

1211

1231

211213

223113

222321

321311

231231

222321

421311

14123113
.
.
.

Comment: it's correct!! thanks!! but why 1231 isn't 3112 like the rest of the lines? first comes the 1 in the above line...

Comment: Hmmm I missed that one. If your friend said it's correct then he made an error as well.

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to
$1,11,21,1211,111221$ which is [OEIS A005150](http://oeis.org/A005150) the look-and-say sequence but I can't make the correspondence.